# What does _: mean in Swift?

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, methods, swift2

So I was doing some reading, and I wanted to know what the following meant. Let's say for instance in Swift, you have a method like `recordResponse(_:)` what does the parameter mean?

I'm working with MVCs and was doing an exercise in a book that had that preset parameter. In the model, I'm supposed to use that method to record a passed answer of "true" or "false" (obviously a string not a boolean), to indicate that a current response was given from a method "currentQuestion".

The exercise in the online book also states that the same method `recordResponse(_:)` should check if the answer given from the question `currentQuestion()` method is correct or not.

Comment: Having an "_" in your declarations means that the "named parameter" will be explicitly unused.

Comment: Hello Dan, let's assume that the named parameter being called in the code is a String, will the parameter accept it? Can you give an example of how '_:' is used? Thanks!

Comment: Basically when you are declaring a function you have two parameters labels for each argument your function will take. The right label represents the internal parameter, this parameter is mandatory. The left label is the "named parameter" this is an optional parameter label that you'll see when calling your function in your code. If you decide to use "_" instead of a name in your declaration, then you will not see a parameter name in your calling code, you simply pass in the value.

Comment: Oh ok, got it thanks Dan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a way of stating the *name* of the function. The function might be declared like this:

```
func recordResponse(s:String) {
    // ...
}
```

Now, by default, the `s` is an internal parameter name only; the external parameter name is suppressed. So we need a *notation* that describes the function, `recordResponse`, as taking one parameter with *no external name*. That notation is `recordResponse(_:)`. The colon follows each parameter name — here there is only one parameter, and has no external name, which is what the underscore indicates.

In the usage you are asking about, this notation is just that: a notation. It's a convention for giving the name of the function in a complete way, when humans talk to humans (as in a tutorial). But in Swift 2.2, this notation will become very important, because it will be *part of the language* — it's how you'll form a *function reference*. That is, it will be Swift's *own* name for the function.

Comment: Thanks, the correct answer goes to both you and Dan.

Answer (score 1):

I am giving a example for this

func test()
{

```
let strOne : String = "hello"
let  _ : String = "Linuxn00b"
print(strOne)
```

}

in let strTwo line xcode produce a warnig that Having an "_"  the "named parameter" will be explicitly unused.Happy coding .